# Refresh parent window when the pop-up window is closed

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any way I can refresh the parent window when a popup window is closed without adding any javascript code to the popup window?

I have a page parent.php on which users can click "open popup" to open a popup window. This popup window shows some flash content and its not possible for me to add something like

```
window.onunload = function(){ 
  window.opener.location.reload(); 
};
```

to the popup window page markup.

Is there any other method to achieve this?
Thanks

Comment: have you tried to add the onunload handler to the handle of the popup window from the parent window?

Comment: like shown by benhowdle below

Comment: Please check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18321323/submit-form-reload-parent-and-close-child/36855748#36855748 might help someone

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To make this work in all major browsers, you need to handle the `unload` event handler in the pop-up and do the reloading in the main window. In the main window, add

```
function popUpClosed() {
    window.location.reload();
}
```

In the pop-up:

```
window.onunload = function() {
    if (window.opener && !window.opener.closed) {
        window.opener.popUpClosed();
    }
};
```

So the answer to your question is generally no, if you need your code to work in all browsers, in particular IE.

Comment: when the URL is secured mean https: does it is not asking for a window with "really want to submit data" Retry and Cancel buttons?

Answer (score 5):

I'm sure you can just add this to parent.php:

```
var myPop = "pop up window selector"
myPop.onunload = function(){ 
  location.reload(); 
};
```

Comment: +1 but could change `var myPop = "pop up window selector"` to `var myPop = window.open();` to make the example clearer

Comment: Sorry, i couldnt think of the selector of the top of my head! Thanks for pointing that out Gordon

Comment: This won't work in IE. My answer will. Please stop upvoting it.

Comment: IE will ignore the `onunload` property assigned from another window. You can only do it from within the pop-up. Try it if you don't believe me (I have IE 7, I'm fairly certain IE 8 behaves the same).

Comment: @benhowdle89: Sorry to be aggressive. It's nothing personal. I'm just having a moment of exasperation with the randomness of SO voting and how it doesn't often reward actual knowledge.

Comment: Sorry Tim i cant stop people upvoting this answer.

Comment: @benhowdle89: I know, and I am genuinely sorry to have picked on you.

Comment: I dont feel picked on :) just sorry that your getting frustrated! Its baffling why people upvote the wrong answer!?

Answer (score 2):

The problem with Tim Down's method is that it doesn't answer the original question. The requirement is that you **cannot** add any code to the pop-up window.

One solution that I've found, while not particularly elegant, is effective across all browsers I've tested on.

You will be simply polling the newly created window object continuously, checking if it's still open.

On parent window:

```
  var register;
  var poll;

  function isOpen(){
      if(register.closed){alert("Closed!"); clearInterval(poll);}
  }


  function create(){

      register = window.open("http://www.google.com","register","width=425,height=550");
      poll=setInterval("isOpen()",100); //Poll every 100 ms.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

had similar problem to detect the closing popup in the parent window. I think the reason was
in not setting the document.domain property.

any way add to Tim Down answer the document.domain property for both window and popup like this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.domain='<?=$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']?>';
    </script>
```

and instead of

```
 window.onunload = function() {
     if (window.opener && !window.opener.closed) {
        window.opener.popUpClosed();
     }
 };
```

I used in the popup :

```
     <body onunload="window.opener.popUpClosed();">
```