# How can I refresh parent page when a pop up is close?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some problems with the function to refresh the main page when a pop is closed.

In my popUp page I have the following javascript

```
$(function () {        
    window.onunload = function () {
        if (window.opener && !window.opener.closed) {
            window.opener.popUpClosed();
        }
    };
});
```

In the main page I have the following javascript

```
$(function () {
    function popUpClosed() {
        window.location.reload();
    }
});
```

I got an error, that the object don't support the method 'popUpClosed'.

I saw this solution on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4267830/refresh-parent-window-when-the-pop-up-window-is-closed) here in StackOverflow, but I don't know how can I fix this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the next answer down:

```
var myPop = "pop up window selector"
myPop.onunload = function(){ 
  location.reload(); 
};
```

*Source: [Refresh parent window when the pop-up window is closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4267830/refresh-parent-window-when-the-pop-up-window-is-closed#4267886)*

### Update

You can get a reference to a window like this:

```
var windowObjectReference = window.open(strUrl, strWindowName[, strWindowFeatures]);
```

*Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.open*

### Update

I just realized that `window.opener.popUpClosed()` is looking for the `popUpClosed()` function in the global scope on the main page, but it's not actually declared in the global scope, try this:

```
var popUpClosed = function () {
    window.location.reload();
};
```

Removing the `document.ready` event handler around this will allow it to be accessible from a child document (like a popup). Also notice the function is now declared like: `var <name> = function () { ... };` which allows it to be accessible via the `window` object.

Comment: But how can I do a selector to get the popup window ?

Comment: @Lucas_Santos I **updated** my answer to demonstrate getting a reference to a window.

Comment: @Lucas_Santos I actually just **updated** my answer again because I think you can fix your code simply by removing the `document.ready` event handler around the `popUpClosed()` function.

Comment: But how can I reload a specific page ? The Parent page and another one ?

Answer (score 0):

It's because `window.opener` does not have any method called `popUpClosed`. Remove the `window.opener` as such:

```
window.onunload = function () {
  if (window.opener && !window.opener.closed) {
    popUpClosed();
  }
};
```

Comment: `window.opener` is a reference to the `window` object for the document that opened the current document. So `window.opener` is like using `window` for a parent document.

Comment: I know what `window.opener` is. I also know that it does not have a `popUpClosed` method. He would need to extend `window.opener`.

Comment: But how can I reload a specific page ? The Parent page and another one ?

Comment: @NickBeranek When you declare anything in the global scope, you can access it via the `window` object. For instance: `var key = 'val'; alert(window.key)` will output `val`. So you can declare a function: `function key () { return 'val'; }` and run its code like this: `window.key();`. So you can add a function to the `window` object and access it from a different document. Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/xZYNk/1/

Comment: Instead of `window.location.reload()`, replace it with `window.opener.location.reload()`.

Comment: @Jasper, `popUpClosed` is NOT chained to `window.opener`. You'd have to declare `var popUpClosed = function() {};` in order to access it from `window`.