# How to refresh page after focus?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to refresh a page after it got back into the focus. For the refreshing part I thought I might just use:

```
location.reload();
```

The tricky part is how do I determine when to refresh?
First the window has to loose the focus (which could be determined through `.blur()` I assume).
Only after the window which lost focus gets back into focus should trigger the refresh of itself. Can I use `.focus()` on location? Or do I have to use something else here?

How can I combine these two cases?

What would your approach be?

Comment: What do you mean by _after it got back into the focus_?

Comment: You probably want `$(window).on('focus', ...)`

Comment: on first focus, set some arbitrary global variable, like `winFocus = 0`;, then use conditional statements. if(winFocus == '0'){ winFocus = '1'} if(winFocus == '1'){ winFocus = 2}if(winFocus == '2'){ location.reload(); } Just re-write the code to work for you, and use it in your focus & blur calls.

Comment: You can use toggle functionality. wherein you change the state when the document loses focus.
When focus in happens again, we check if the state was previously changed by blur.

Comment: As a user, I can't imagine I want a page refreshing itself automatically when I go back to it from somewhere else.

Comment: Let's say the user is browsing in a popup for a while. So the current page would loose its focus, right? Now I thought after the user closes this popup it will be back in focus?! This is when I would need to refresh the page.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301278/refresh-parent-window-when-closing-child-window and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4267830/refresh-parent-window-when-the-pop-up-window-is-closed and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318006/reload-parent-window-from-child-window

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try this:

```
var blurred = false;
window.onblur = function() { blurred = true; };
window.onfocus = function() { blurred && (location.reload()); };
```

This only reloads the page if it has been hidden

I don't recommend binding to the window focus in jQuery, the Page will reload on pretty much every user action.

**Update**

This heavily relies on the browser implementation of window.onfocus and window.onblur. Webkit may not support the onblur event (in my chromium it didn't) where firefox calls a blur if the page is hidden.

Comment: What does "blurred" do in the following?
blurred && (location.reload());

Comment: @helga blurred is false initially, set to true onBlur. blurred&& checks if blurred is true or false

Comment: @DavChana Oooh, so it's a shortcut for IF without ELSE. I didn't know that, thanks!

Comment: How can I make this code work when the user clicks in a textarea inside of a bootstrap modal? It seems that on mobile browsers, it causes an entire page refresh.

Answer (score 20):

In my development environment I add this snippet of JS to a page - whenever the page becomes active after becoming inactive it reloads, so for example if you type in your text editor then  click back onto your browser the page will reload once without an infinite loop. It also works when chaining active tab or active window within the same browser session.

```
window.onblur= function() {window.onfocus= function () {location.reload(true)}};
```

As stated above this does depend on browser implementation but works fine in chrome.

Answer (score 3):

@Eamonn 's approach works good for chrome as mentioned by him.

For Firefox:

```
window.disableResetPrompt;
window.onblur= function() {window.onfocus= function () {location.reload(true)}};
```