# Window.onblur with if statement

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, settimeout

I am building kind of clock and I strongly need to use `settimeout()`.

However, Google Chrome and Safari doesn't allow `settimeout()` when tab inactive. So, I decided to reloading page when tab active again. (I know, it's not proper way to do it, but I am new at javascript and tried to learn.) I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16406350/7480762) answer and tried to implement to my case. But there is a challenge, I have 3 modals in this page and I don't want reload page when modals are open.

So, I added a global variable equels an integer then changed the value of variable when modals are open.

Here is my code,

```
var modalCheck = 2;

function openModal() {
    var doneModal = document.getElementById("done");
    var done = document.getElementsByClassName("closeMessage")[0];

    modalCheck = 1;

    doneModal.style.display = "block";

    done.onclick = function() {
        doneModal.style.display = "none";
        modalCheck = 2;
    }

    window.onclick = function(event) {
        if (event.target == doneModal) {
            doneModal.style.display = "none";
            modalCheck = 2;
        }
    }
}

window.onblur = function() {
    window.onfocus= function () {
        if (modalCheck = 2) {
            console.log(modalCheck);
            location.reload(true);
        }
    }
};
```

Page reloading is still working, but if modals are opened page reaload immediately.

My question is why this is not working? Is there a syntax error or something like that? What is the solution?

Comment: What kind of comparison is this: `modalCheck = 2`?

Comment: I tried to use boolean but if it is globally setted it didn't change situation.

Comment: As Teemu mentioned, can you try  ```modalCheck == 2```

Comment: First off, you should open the Developer Tools for your browser. That will give you information about errors, especially syntax errors. Next, maybe look at it from a different angle. Why do you need to have a timer running even when the tab is inactive?

Comment: @omerkocaaga Please take a look at your own code a couple of lines above the said line, there's another `if`, which is written properly.

Comment: @VamshiGudipati I didn't get your answer. Can you be more specific on this?

Comment: @omerkocaaga I'm going to steal your heureka experience, `=` is an assignment operator, comparison operators are `==` and `===`.

Comment: @MikeC I need because I have a function which change every minutes (`if second === 0`) a divs style. If I didn't add this function in a `settimeout()` it fails. So it looks I need it. But when chrome or safari tabs are inactive, `settimeout()` doesn't work sadly. So I asked this question. What are your solutions?

Comment: @omerkocaaga Okay but do you really need to change the way an element looks when no one is looking? `setTimeout` will still result in a function being executed, it just won't happen when no one is looking at it.

Comment: @Teemu thank you very much. Sometimes, my brain decided to stop working.

Comment: @MikeC Think about you are building a clock. But here is a challenge. If users change the browser tab clock start to show time wrong. Could anyone use this clock?

Comment: @omerkocaaga Sure. You just need to change how you're calculating what time it is. Save the start time right when you start the clock. Use `setTimeout` to update every second or so. Get the current time. Compare it against the start time. Voila, a working clock.

Comment: @MikeC You forgot minutes must be change every "minute". It's not just showing time when page is open. It must be show time properly everytime.

Comment: @omerkocaaga Seconds, minutes, whatever. It makes no difference. [Here's an example of it working.](https://jsfiddle.net/7vLffuco/)

Comment: @MikeC Your example works on chrome. I didn't get it totally, but I tried to understand this. I am really new on javascript. Thank you very much.

Comment: @MikeC I looked at your code again and figured it out. But I changed logic a little. I get time when onblur and set a cookie then get time onfocus and add minutes as difference. Then I remove cookie. Again, thanks a lot. You change my whole perspective on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the problem:

```
if ( modalCheck = 2 ) {
```

This "if" condition is always true, because you're actually assigning the value "2" to "modalCheck" rather than checking whether "modalCheck" equals "2". The assignment resolves to the value "2", which is treated as a "truthy" expression in your if statement. So this if statement never fails. I recommend

```
if ( modalCheck === 2 ) {
```

Others have suggested "if ( modalCheck == 2 ) {", but it's generally better to compare using === rather than == to avoid unexpected weirdness.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know what your html part is, try this code

```
   var modalCheck = 2;

    function openModal() {
        var doneModal = document.getElementById("done");
        var done = document.getElementsByClassName("closeMessage")[0];

        modalCheck = 1;

        doneModal.style.display = "block";

        done.onclick = function() {
            doneModal.style.display = "none";
            modalCheck = 2;
        }

        window.onclick = function(event) {
            if (event.target == doneModal) {
                doneModal.style.display = "none";
                modalCheck = 2;
            }
        }
    }

    window.onblur = function() {
     this.addEventListener('focus',function(){
        if (modalCheck == 2) {
                console.log(modalCheck);
                location.reload(true);
         }});

        };
```