# Reload Page on Focus

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a Progressive Web App that I need to refresh every time the user opens it.

To achieve this I have tried:

```
1) First Option
window.onblur = function() {
    window.onfocus= function () {
        window.location = self.location;
    }
};

2) Second Option
var blurred = false;
window.onblur = function() { 
    blurred = true; 
};
window.onfocus = function() {
    blurred && (window.location = self.location); 
};
```

Credit of Option 1: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16406350/11843328

Credit of Option 2: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11313719/11843328

This work well but the problem is that sometimes whenever you click something, it reloads again. It basically reloads like 4 times in a row with some action. Other times it works as expected, just reloading once, but most of the times is like 4 or 5 times in a row.

I need it to reload just once when opened (on focus). Is there any alternatives I could try or any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean by open? Do you mean `onload`, like when the page is loaded for the first time? Or do you mean `onfocus`, when the window gets focus? Little confused about which event your targeting, but I will leave an answer when I know more.

Comment: @Christian it's ```onfocus```

Comment: Is there a reason why you're not using onload?

Comment: I am also note sure what you wanted to do on that function executing on  window.onfocus because it just puts blurred && (window.location = self.location); which does not make any sense. Please look at your question again?

Comment: @MosiaThabo Yes, because I'm using this function for iOS PWA, it caches a version of the opened app, so whenever you open the app, you get the same state as how it was because it's basically a "bookmark" so the page is already loaded, this is why onFocus works for whenever they "open" it.

Comment: @MosiaThabo I edited with credits on where I got the code

Comment: Makes sense now. Thanks MCM for the clarity. The Blurred variable being put there in the function is the one causing confusion "__blurred__ && (window.location = self.location);"

Comment: This is very user-hostile. If you want to do this, it should be based on a button click or happen automatically in the background. If go back to a previously opened tab and then it immediately reloads, then I'd be a bit confused.

Comment: @volt Do you have any advice on how I can achieve reload in the background? this is my ultimate goal but I cannot find any help. I don't know if I'm not looking/searching with the correct words.

Comment: @MCM13 That's honestly not a question that I can answer in a "comment." That said, I can say with some degree of certainty that if that's your end goal, then you'd need to look at the available single page-application frameworks for inspiration like ember (of the top of my head).

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're using `window` focus event. As others have pointed out, there is no need to use the `blur` event, as `focus` will only fire if the window focus was blurred.

You can use the `window.location.reload` method to reload the window as well.

```js
window.addEventListener("focus", e => window.location.reload());
```

```html
<p>Look for a flicker</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the onblur event. Using just the onfocus event will do the work.