# Support didChangeAppLifecycleState for flutter web?

Tags: flutter, web, dart, flutter-web

I want to refresh the whole website if the app has been paused. DidChangeAppLifecycleState works smoothly on ios and android but does not support flutter web. Is there an alternative?

Comment: You can pretty much do this using JS inside your `index.html` page as suggested in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11313434/how-to-refresh-page-after-focus). If you need a pure `dart:html` based solution, let me know I will try out some solution. In theory this should be possible. But beware of implementations of the browser as suggested in the original post.

Comment: Thank you a lot for the tipp. The issue is that the javascript solution does not support webkit. It would be awesome if you have a solution for webkit either in js or css.

Comment: Have you tried the other answer in that with 15 votes. She/He claims it works in chorme. Which browser are you testing.?

Comment: thank you, yes it worked. I know this is luxury, but do know how to do that in ecosia?

Comment: Sorry, what is ecosia..?

Comment: Hi @GeorgPanteleev, I am also struggling with the same issue. Can you briefly explain how did you achieve this?