# refresh base window from pop up window in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am opening a popup window *B* from page *A* using:

```
this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(  
      this.GetType(), 
      "JavaScript", 
     "myWindow=window.open('B.aspx',
     'WindowName',
     'copyhistory=no, 
     width=800, 
     height=300, 
     top=150, 
     left=50, 
     resizable=1, 
     scrollbars=1');
     myWindow.focus();", 
     true
);
```

I want to refresh page *A* whenever there is a change in popup window *B*.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do it:

```
<script>
    window.onunload = refreshParent;
    function refreshParent() {
        window.opener.location.reload();
    }
</script>

<script language="JavaScript">
<!--
function refreshParent() {
  window.opener.location.href = window.opener.location.href;

  if (window.opener.progressWindow)

 {
    window.opener.progressWindow.close()
  }
  window.close();
}
//-->
</script>
```

Sources:

[Open popup and refresh parent page on close popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10792408/open-popup-and-refresh-parent-page-on-close-popup)

http://forums.devarticles.com/javascript-development-22/auto-refresh-parent-window-after-closing-popup-4864.html

[Refresh parent window when the pop-up window is closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4267830/refresh-parent-window-when-the-pop-up-window-is-closed)

Answer (score 0):

Call `refreshParent` on user actions as :

```
function refreshParent() {
     window.opener.location.href = window.opener.location.href;
}
```